# How to show validation errors in a Django Model form using DateTimeField and input_formats

Tags: python, django

I want to enforce a particular date-time format using Django's model form --

```
Class ModelEditForm(forms.ModelForm):
    date_one = forms.DateTimeField(input_formats=["%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"])

    class Meta:
    model = MyModel
    fields = (date_one,
              )
```

My form.html file --

```
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="form-group col-sm-12 col-md-12">
            <label> Enter date and time in this format "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"  </label>
            {% render_field form.date_one class="form-control"%}
        </div>
       {% csrf_token %}
             <div class="row">
            <div class="form-group col-sm-6 col-md-6">
                <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Save</button>
            </div>
</form>
```

[image: screenshot of the form]

As shown in the above picture if the correct date-time format (e.g., 2019-09-16 14:00:00) is entered the form is saved, but a wrong format (e.g., 2019-09-02 14) would not show an error message like it does for other ModelForm fields, e.g, enforcing a max_digit in model.DecimalField. Using wrong format does not update the form but the user doesn't know why the form is not saved. What can I do to show the error message without using a JavaScript input.

I am using Django 2.0, Python 3.6 and widget_tweaks.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

The question is not clear but you can deal as follows
Timestamp to add time and date for the first time
updated To update the time and date

in models

```
class Sign(models.Model):
email = models.EmailField()
FullName = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=False, null=True)
timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False)
updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=False, auto_now=True)

def __str__(self):
    return self.email
```

in form

```
class SignUpForm(forms.ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = Sign
    fields = ["FullName", "email"]
```

i'm use admin You can use the code in the views

```
class SignUp(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ["__str__", "timestamp", "updated"]
    form = SignUpForm

    class Meta:
        model = Sign
admin.site.register(Sign, SignUp)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I edited the question and added a screenshot of the form showing what I really want to do. I cannot use auto_now, the dates need to to manually entered.